# Save UITableView names to array on button action

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to save the names that are filled in UITableView to an array

```
var mineSpillere = [String]()
```

How can I do this on buttonAction?

This is button action for how i add names to tableview:

```
@IBAction func addButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
            mineSpillere.append(namesTextBox.text)
            myTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

and also here code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = self.mineSpillere[indexPath.row]

        return cell;
    }
```

That only when I press the "back" button in the application, the names from the UITableView will be saved in an array.

I am going to access these names from another view controller also, so i need them to be saved as an array.

Comment: What names do you mean?  How did they get into the `UITableView`?

Comment: @PhillipMills -  I add them using textbox and button.

Comment: Could you post the code on how you put them into the tableView's cell?

Comment: @StephenFox - Added now!

Comment: So when you press the `back` button you want a copy of `mineSpillere`?

Comment: @StephenFox - When i press back button, i want to save tableview items to array, because i want to access that array from another view controller.

Comment: Okay well seeing as your calling `-reloadData()` on the tableView it would be helpful if we could see your tableView delegate method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` just so we can see exactly how those cells are being set.

Comment: @StephenFox - Added now, take a look :)

Comment: Well seeing as you're setting the tableview cells with the mineSpillere array, I assume the array already has the names. You could use a delegate callback to pass the array when the back button is pressed.

Comment: @StephenFox - what do you mean with "use a delegate callback to pass the array when the back button is pressed"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it looks like you have all the data in the `mineSpillere` array already as you're using `cell.textLabel!.text = self.mineSpillere[indexPath.row]` so to get that array back to the first view controller. You could use the following code in the view controller that is being presented when the 'back' button is being pressed:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController,SecondViewControllerDelegate {


    var mineSpillereCopyFromSecondVC = [String]()




    func presentSecondViewController() {
        // Im not sure the class name for you're second view
        // where the tableView is located.
        var secondVC: SecondViewController = SecondViewController();
        secondVC.delegate = self

        // Also not too sure on how you're presenting the `SecondViewController` so I'm goingg to leave that empty. 
        // The important part is just above us.
    }


    func passMineSpillere(mineSpillere: [String]) {
        // This class now has the mineSpiller array of name.
        self.mineSpillereCopyFromSecondVC = mineSpillere
    }

}
```

And then in you SecondViewController where the tableView is located you could add the following code.

```
import UIKit

protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func passMineSpillere(mineSpillere:[String])
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?
    var mineSpillere = [String]()

    // This will be called when the 'back' button is pressed.
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pass the mineSpillere array back to the delegate
        // which is the firstViewController instance.
        self.delegate?.passMineSpillere(self.mineSpillere)
    }


}
```

Comment: Error at code: "secondVC.delegate = self": - "Cannot assign a value of type "FirstViewController" to a value of type "SecondViewControllerDelegate?"

Comment: You must make sure your FirstViewController conforms to SecondViewControllerDelegate which is done at the declaration of your class.  `class FirstViewController: UIViewController,SecondViewControllerDelegate {`